# How to run command when reboot my Centos server

Tags: linux, node.js, centos

I will run one command after my server is rebooted only once

I have chat application on my server by node.js

This is command line I write by putty and run my chat application

login to server

```
[root@name ~]# cd /
[root@name /]# cd /home/admin/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/chat_server
[root@name chat_server]# forever start websocket.js
info:    Forever processing file: websocket.js
[root@name chat_server]#
```

How run Automatic?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `rc.local` script. See [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html).

Comment: Hi Dear, how add to rc.local sorry I'm beginner

Comment: Well, it's a simple shell script... You can adjust it to your needs! From the link I posted: `Adding commands to the bottom of this script is an easy way to perform necessary tasks like starting special services [...]`